# Trouble setting color for TimePicker XML Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

As you can see, AM and PM have a very hard to see color when selected, Cancel and OK are very hard to see, and I would prefer a different color for the highlighting behind 10:00. I just don't know the attribute names, I've tried so many different things including looking into documentation, I just need help understanding what I am missing/doing wrong

[image]

This is what it currently looks like, and the XML that accompanies it:

```
<!-- Clock dialog -->
<style name="TimePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="materialClockStyle">@style/TimePicker.Clock</item>
    <item name="materialButtonOutlinedStyle">@style/TimePicker.Button</item>
    <item name="chipStyle">@style/TimePicker.Chip</item>
    <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/TimePicker.ImageButton</item>
</style>

<style name="TimePicker.Clock" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Clock">
    <item name="clockFaceBackgroundColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="clockHandColor">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
    <item name="clockNumberTextColor">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>
</style>

<style name="TimePicker.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="TimePicker.Chip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Display">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>
</style>

<style name="TimePicker.ImageButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.ImageButton">
    <item name="iconTint">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>
</style>
```

My colors for this light theme:

```
<!-- Light mode -->
<color name="blue">#4984BF</color>

<color name="colorPrimary">#ECECEC</color> <!-- Even Brighter Light Gray -->
<color name="colorPrimaryVariant">#AAAAAA</color> <!-- Muted Gray -->
<color name="colorOnPrimary">#000000</color> <!-- Black -->
<color name="colorSecondary">#B0C7A1</color> <!-- Soft Green -->
<color name="colorSecondaryVariant">#9CB68C</color> <!-- Muted Soft Green -->
<color name="colorOnSecondary">#01140b</color> <!-- Black Green -->
<color name="statusBarColor">#AAAAAA</color> <!-- Muted Gray -->
```

While making the app I'm currently working on, theming my app has by far been the most trouble for me, I don't know if I'm not understanding basic fundamentals about it or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style name="TimePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
```

this was the answer, this changes the highlighted areas

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).